# Building graph of "adjacent" strings

Tags: algorithm, string, language-agnostic, graph

I've got a set of strings, and need to build a graph where strings are the nodes, and there's an edge between any pair of *adjacent* strings.

To strings `A` and `B` are said to be *adjacent* if by adding, removing, or replacing a single character of `A` (at whatever position) you get `B`.

For example `scar` and `car` are adjacent (removing the `s` from `scar`), so are `car` and `far` (replacing `c` with `f`) and so are `far` and `farm` (adding `m`).

Is it possible to do this in less than `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compute `n(n - 1)/2 = O(n^2)` entries in the adjacency matrix (the entries are 1 if the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is 1, and 0 otherwise). There is no way to avoid this.

(Note that given `n`, I can find an alphabet and a collection of words on that alphabet such that all `n` words are neighbors and the graph would be complete.)

Comment: As the Edit Distance is a distance, the triangular inequality holds. I think that in the general case you can partition the space recursively holding subsets with distance <= 2 to the last point examined as candidates, and discard to calculate the other elements of the AM. In the worst case, all elements will stay in the same subset forever.

Comment: That's the point of my complete graph example. It is the worst case.

Comment: The graph doesn't have to be stored as an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Nabb: What's your point? There are `n choose 2` possible edges. It has to be determined for each possible edge whether or not it is in the graph. In the worst case every edge must be explicitly checked.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not possible.

In the worst case, all words are neighbors. Example 6 words={cat, fat, rat, mat, sat, at}.

In this example you need to establish (n) * (n-1)/2 = 6 * 5/2 = 15 edges.

So you need O(n^2) operations just to set up the edges in the worst case ... no matter how many comparisons or loops you need, you can't better that.